# Through xPression (Product from EMC) how we can send email notifications?

Tags: emc

Through xPression (Product from EMC) how we can send email notifications??

is there any other way like through SMTP?

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can do it !

Using xPression we can dynamically generate text / attachment and generate an email .

It has an inbuilt SMTP server to handle the emails distribution .

Configure the output mechanism to a email usinf xAdmin interface .